# XML files generated in SAS formatted differently since upgrade

Tags: xml, sas

My organisation has recently upgraded from SAS 9.1 to SAS 9.4 and the dozens of reports that are set up to export to XML are now being formatted differently. The data reports haven't changed; however, the XML files generated using ODS and the default tagset include extra data which is making publishing the data difficult.

At first I thought it was an encoding issue but I have changed this to 
windows-1252 and am still experiencing the same problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what the question is?

Comment: Talk to tech support and read the docs regarding upgrade. The change may have occurred in 9.2, 9.3 or 9.4 so tech support is your best bet.

Comment: Sorry, the question should have been - does anybody know of any changes that would have affected this? Or any tips on what to check?

Comment: Thanks Reeza - I logged a call with tech support earlier so hopefully they'll have some more info. Can't see anything in the upgrade docs.